# React.js : Search String to Highlight text inside braces {..}

Tags: javascript, reactjs

currently, I stuck with a logic where I want to implement a functionality :

I have an input box from where I am saving values to 'state' as array[] and mapping them into list for UI.

I want to Implement if the list have any value inside enclosed braces {.. } it change its background color only.

ex: I have a {list} of array

solution : I have a `list` of array

any help and logical direction toward a solution will be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My bad It was easy with RegEx
Solution

```
let re = new RegExp(/{[\w{}]+}/g)
var hlooo = re.exec('hello man this is {text} oh {yeahhh}');
console.log(hlooo)
```

Thanks all for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Does includes() method work for you?
[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.includes(2); // true
```